# Triggering a class with its own id with find

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I am using a waypoint to trigger specific elements. The div elements below all have the same class, so I am trying to trigger the id and then `find` the element's class and then `addClass('fadeDisplay').

Initially I tried creating a function for it to reduce the code, but once I could not get '$(this)`to work with it, I attempted to do it by writing each specific element, like this`$('#section3-box-img1')`.

My class is not adding and the waypoint element is firing in the correct place.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="section3-box-img" id="section3-box-img1"></div>
<div class="section3-box-img" id="section3-box-img2"></div>
<div class="section3-box-img" id="section3-box-img3"></div>

var section3img = $('.section3-box-img');
$('#section3-box-img1').waypoint(function() {
//section3Fade();
    $('#section3-box-img1').find(section3img).addClass('fadeDisplay');
}, {
    offset: '75%'
});
function section3Fade() {
    $(this).find('.section3-box-img').addClass('fadeDisplay');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Removed the find function. (i don't know why u want to find the class if you are using an id). Try Something like Below.

```
$('#section3-box-img1').waypoint(function() {
//section3Fade();
    $('#section3-box-img1').addClass('fadeDisplay');
}, {
    offset: '75%'
});

function section3Fade() {
    $(this).addClass('fadeDisplay');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of 'this' keyword. Something like this:

```
<div class="section3-box-img" id="section3-box-img1"></div>
<div class="section3-box-img" id="section3-box-img2"></div>
<div class="section3-box-img" id="section3-box-img3"></div>

var section3img = $('.section3-box-img');
$('#section3-box-img1').waypoint(function() {
    $(this).addClass('fadeDisplay');
}, {
    offset: '75%'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[id^='section3-box-img']").waypoint(function() {
    $(this).addClass('fadeDisplay');
}, {
    offset: '75%'
});
```